# Что означает сообщение при загрузке kernel32.dll". Невозможно найти или открыть PDB-файл

Tags: visual-studio-2015

kernel32.dll". Невозможно найти или открыть PDB-файл.
Что это такое?

Comment: pdb-файл содержит данные для отладки

Comment: при загрузке чего?

Answer (score 1):

Откройте

> Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> Symbols

Установите галочку `Microsoft Symbol Servers`, Visual Studio скачает нужные pdb-файлы.

Можно отключить уведомления

> Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> Output Window -> Module Load Messages -> Off